# Adding dates based on week numbers in data table to use in GoogleVis

Tags: android, sql

I have a data table like this:

Location      Week      Sales       Cost

A            0         15          11

A            1         18          11

A            2         18           9

A           123        12          10

B            0         20           6

B            1         0            17

B            2         17           15

B           123        15           9

This data is for 2 and a half years for couple of locations. I have the week numbers, 0 to 123, but I want to have a specific date in each week goes week by week to use in googleVis package (for example, 2012-01-05 then 2012-01-10 and so on).

Please kindly help me in this.

Comment: Any chance you could format your table description a little better? I can't tell what those letters and numbers mean.

Comment: I edited the table, hope it works now.

Comment: How are choosing which dates belong in which `Week` numbers? What is your definition of a `Week` value? Since 2012 begins on a Saturday and `2012-01-05` apparently is associated with week# 0 and `2012-01-10` is five days later and in week# 1, you must have a chosen method of assigning `Week`. What method are you using?